# Codeigniter - Upload multiple files and displaying files

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

My web app only allows for one file upload which is an issue because users want to be able to submit 2 or more files when necessary. 
Please how do I allow multiple file uploads and displaying those files to be downloaded by another type of users?

***MODEL***

```
  public function upload_docs($data)
    {

   $this->db->where('homework_id',$data['homework_id']);
   $this->db->where('student_id',$data['student_id']);
   $q = $this->db->get('submit_assignment');

   if ( $q->num_rows() > 0 ) 
   {
      $this->db->where('homework_id',$data['homework_id']);
       $this->db->where('student_id',$data['student_id']);
      $this->db->update('submit_assignment',$data);
   } else {

      $this->db->insert('submit_assignment',$data);
   }

    }
```

***CONTROLLER***

```
 public function upload_docs()
    {

        $homework_id         = $_REQUEST['homework_id'];
        $student_id          =$_REQUEST['student_id'];
        $data['homework_id'] = $homework_id;
        $data['student_id']  = $student_id;
        $data['message']     = $_REQUEST['message'];
        // $data['id']=$_POST['assigment_id'];
         $is_required=$this->homework_model->check_assignment($homework_id,$student_id);
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', $this->lang->line('message'), 'trim|required|xss_clean');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('file', $this->lang->line('attach_document'), 'trim|xss_clean|callback_handle_upload['.$is_required.']');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
          $msg=array(
            'message'=>form_error('message'),
            'file'=>form_error('file'),
          );
          $array = array('status' => 'fail', 'error' => $msg, 'message' => '');

        }else{

             if (isset($_FILES["file"]) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
                $time     = md5($_FILES["file"]['name'] . microtime());
                $fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                $img_name = $time . '.' . $fileInfo['extension'];           
            $data['docs'] =  $img_name;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "./uploads/homework/assignment/" . $data['docs']);

            $data['file_name']=$_FILES["file"]['name'];

            $this->homework_model->upload_docs($data);
        }

         $array = array('status' => 'success', 'error' => '', 'message' => $this->lang->line('success_message'));
        }

        echo json_encode($array);
    }

    public function handle_upload($str,$is_required)
    {

        $image_validate = $this->config->item('file_validate');

        if (isset($_FILES["file"]) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

            $file_type         = $_FILES["file"]['type'];
            $file_size         = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
            $file_name         = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $allowed_extension = $image_validate['allowed_extension'];
            $ext               = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);



            $allowed_mime_type = $image_validate['allowed_mime_type'];

            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $mtype = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            finfo_close($finfo);

            if (!in_array($mtype, $allowed_mime_type)) {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', 'File Type Not Allowed');
                return false;
            }

            if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_extension) || !in_array($file_type, $allowed_mime_type)) {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', 'Extension Not Allowed');
                return false;
            }

            if ($file_size > $image_validate['upload_size']) {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', $this->lang->line('file_size_shoud_be_less_than') . number_format($image_validate['upload_size'] / 1048576, 2) . " MB");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } else {
          if($is_required==0){
             $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', 'Please choose a file to upload.');
            return false;
          }else{
             return true;
          }

        }


    }
```

***VIEW***

```
 <form id="upload" role="form" method="post" class="ptt10" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_docs">
                <div class="modal-body pt0">
                            <div class="row">
                                <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $student_id; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" id="homework_id"  name="homework_id">
                                <input type="hidden" id="assigment_id" name="assigment_id">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="pwd"><?php echo $this->lang->line('message'); ?></label>
                                        <textarea type="text" id="assigment_message" name="message" class="form-control "></textarea>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="pwd"><?php echo $this->lang->line('attach_document'); ?></label>
                                        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="form-control filestyle">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p id="uploaded_docs"></p>
                            </div>


                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <div class="" id="footer_area">
                        <button type="submit" form="upload" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="submit" data-loading-text='Please wait...'><?php echo $this->lang->line('save'); ?></button>
</div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This is displayed like this

***controller***

```
 public function assigmnetDownload($doc)
    {
        $this->load->helper('download');
        $name     = $this->uri->segment(5);
        $ext      = explode(".", $name);
        $filepath = "./uploads/homework/assignment/" . $doc;
        $data     = file_get_contents($filepath);
        force_download($name, $data);
    }
```

view

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered example">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('name') ?></th>
                                                <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('message') ?></th>

                                                <th class="text-right"><?php echo $this->lang->line('action') ?></th>
                                            </tr>

                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="homework_docs_result">
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

***Thanks to all helping me out. I did as you guys directed. However, I noticed I'm able to select multiple files now but gets stuck on the save button.
When I click, nothing happens. Data is not submitted.
This is what I have done so far***

controller

```
  if (isset($_FILES["file"])){
            foreach($_FILES["file"] as $file){ 
            if(!empty($file["name"])){
                $time     = md5($file["file"]['name'] . microtime());
                $fileInfo = pathinfo($file["file"]["name"]);
                $img_name = $time . '.' . $fileInfo['extension'];           
            $data['docs'] =  $img_name;
            move_uploaded_file($file["file"]["tmp_name"], "./uploads/homework/assignment/" . $data['docs']);

            $data['file_name']=$file["file"]['name'];

            $this->homework_model->upload_docs($data);
        }

         $array = array('status' => 'success', 'error' => '', 'message' => $this->lang->line('success_message'));
        }

        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    }
    }
```

view

```
 <form id="upload" role="form" method="post" class="ptt10" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploaded_docs">
<input type="file"  multiple=""  id="file" name="file[]" class="form-control filestyle">
<button type="submit" form="upload" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="submit" data-loading-text=' Please wait'><?php echo $this->lang->line('save'); ?></button>
</form>
```

Comment: i lazy to fix your code, but will give a clue. for <input=file>, add ''multiple'' attribute. then, from your backend, you need to loop it. usually it will be in array. also, you might want to look into how to sanitize file upload.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20138535/11024771

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" class="form-control filestyle">
```

Setting name to `file[]` will accept array of files

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_FILES["file"]){
   foreach($_FILES["file"] as $file){ //this loop will get one file from 'file[]' array at a time
       if(!empty($file["name"])){
            //your alreay written code
            //replace $_FILES["file"] with $file
       }
   }
}
```

Hope this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Some tips, if help. Do not forget the vote to strengthen. Let's go...

```
<form method="post" action="upload_docs" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input name="filesToUpload[]" type="file" multiple="" />
</form>
```

On your controller it's simple ...

```
if(isset($_FILES['filesToUpload'])) {
  foreach ($_FILES['filesToUpload'] as $fileUp) {
    $time = md5($fileUp["file"]['name'].microtime());
    $fileInfo = pathinfo($fileUp["file"]["name"]);
    $img_name = "{$time}.{$fileInfo['extension']}";
    $data['docs'] = $img_name;
    move_uploaded_file($fileUp["file"]["tmp_name"], "./uploads/homework/assignment/{$data['docs']}");
    $data['file_name']=$fileUp["file"]['name'];
    $this->homework_model->upload_docs($data);
  }
}
```

To display multiple files you need to use the same concept as uploading working with

> `foreach($files as $file){ ... }`

I hope I helped. Success!

Answer (score 0):

Setting attribute `multiple` will allow selecting multiple files at once by pressing `ctrl`, setting the name as an array(`file[]`) will allow more than files name to be stored.

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" class="form-control filestyle" multiple>
```

However, if you don't want the user to upload multiple files at once then you'll have to make multiple `input` fields with the same name as an array(`file[]`)

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" class="form-control filestyle">
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file[]" class="form-control filestyle">
...
...
```

In your controller, you'll have to traverse through each element as it is now an array.

```
foreach($_FILES["file"]['name'] as $file){ //single element 

    echo $file; // returns the name of file
    // your-logic-to-upload

}
```

If you're having trouble uploading multiple files, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471811/multiple-image-upload-with-codeigniter-saving-only-one-file-path-to-mysql-databa), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113832/multiple-files-upload-in-codeigniter) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007970/codeigniter-multiple-image-upload-and-store-to-database).
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hello, I modified my post. Please see what i have done. I'm able to select multiple files now but when I click the save button, nothing happens

Comment: change your `action` to `echo base_url()."your-controller/upload_docs"`, if you're having trouble uploading files, refer to the `3` links I provided, they help you with the uploading process